# Replace value in variable based on other variables

Tags: stata

Assuming I have the following dataset, which has a few missing entries for `Country`:

```
clear

input strL Person      strL Country     Population  
           'ABC'       "USA"              3999 
           'ABC'       " "                 544 
           'ABC'       " "                7546 
           'ABD'       "China"           10000 
           'BCG'       "India"            6789 
           'BCG'        " "               5454 
           'ABD'        " "              10000 
end
```

I wish to replace missing countries with the matching values in `Person`. For all `Person` 'ABC', the country should be the same.

I need a solution that differs from manually scripting `replace Country = "USA" if Person == "ABC"` as my dataset has more than 10,000 unique observations for `Person`.

The dataset should look like the following:

```
           Person      Country         Population  
           'ABC'       "USA"              2514 
           'ABC'       "USA"               388 
           'ABC'       "USA"              8245 
           'ABD'       "China"           10000 
           'BCG'       "India"            6789 
           'BCG'       "India"            5454 
           'ABD'       "China"           10000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input and output don't match Stata standards. Stata does not use single quotes as string delimiters or show string delimiters in listings.

Stata doesn't regard one or more spaces as string missing.

Nevertheless this may help for a string variable such as `Country`:

```
clear

input strL Person      strL Country     Population  
           "ABC"       "USA"              3999 
           "ABC"       " "                 544 
           "ABC"       " "                7546 
           "ABD"       "China"           10000 
           "BCG"       "India"            6789 
           "BCG"        " "               5454 
           "ABD"        " "              10000 
end

bysort Person (Country) : replace Country = Country[_N] if missing(trim(Country)) 

list, sepby(Person)

     +-----------------------------+
     | Person   Country   Popula~n |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. |    ABC       USA       7546 |
  2. |    ABC       USA        544 |
  3. |    ABC       USA       3999 |
     |-----------------------------|
  4. |    ABD     China      10000 |
  5. |    ABD     China      10000 |
     |-----------------------------|
  6. |    BCG     India       5454 |
  7. |    BCG     India       6789 |
     +-----------------------------+
```

Comment: this helped. how would this change if the missing variable I was trying to impute was a floating number?

Comment: Missing numerics sort to the end so you to reference numericvar`[1]` rather than strvar`[_N]`.

Comment: Your example is simple -- beyond the serious detail that strings that are just spaces are not treated as missing -- in that there is only one non-missing value within each group of observations, so the issue is just the mechanics of copying it to overwrite missings.  It may be that in a large dataset you need to check for consistency.